# Verilog - Line 49: Assignment under multiple single edges is not supported for synthesis

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I tried to change a variety of different issues like the begin-end statements but nothing seems to be working. I also tried changing the reg [3:0] to [7:0] since I was also getting some warnings

I'm not sure why I keep getting this error:

```
#  Line 49: Assignment under multiple single edges is not supported for synthesis
```

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module FSM (CLK, U, D, CL, Z);  
     
 input CLK, U, D, CL; 
 reg [3:0] count;
 output reg [3:0] Z;
 
 always @ (posedge CLK or posedge CL) begin
    if(CL)
        count <= 0;
    else
            begin
        if(U)
        begin
            if(count == 8)
            count <= 0;
                else
            count <= count +1;
            end
            if(D)
            begin
            if(count == 0)
                count <= 8;
            else
                count <= count -1;
            end
        end
        
if(count==0)
    Z<=8;
if(count==1)
    Z<=2;
if(count==2)
    Z<=6;
if(count==3)
    Z<=4;
if(count==4)
    Z<=6;
if(count==5)
    Z<=8;
if(count==6)
    Z<=0;
if(count==7)
    Z<=7;
if(count==8)
    Z<=8;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The synthesis tool might be confused because `Z` is not asynchronously reset by the `CL` signal, like `count` is.

I think it would be better to reset `Z` and to separate your code into 2 `always` blocks:

```
module FSM (CLK, U, D, CL, Z);  
   
    input CLK, U, D, CL; 
    reg [3:0] count;
    output reg [3:0] Z;
   
    always @ (posedge CLK or posedge CL) begin
        if (CL)
            count <= 0;
        else begin
           if (U) begin
                if (count == 8)
                    count <= 0;
                else
                    count <= count + 1;
            end
            if (D) begin
                if (count == 0)
                    count <= 8;
                else
                    count <= count - 1;
            end
        end
    end

    always @ (posedge CLK or posedge CL) begin
        if (CL) begin
            Z <= 0;
        end else begin
            case (count)
                0: Z <= 8;
                1: Z <= 2;
                2: Z <= 6;
                3: Z <= 4;
                4: Z <= 6;
                5: Z <= 8;
                6: Z <= 0;
                7: Z <= 7;
                8: Z <= 8;
            endcase
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Note that I also used a `case` statement for `Z` to simplify the code and make the intent more apparent.